# Using Operations on a List in Python and Aggregating Results in New List

Tags: python, loops

I have a list of numbers, all of which need to be divided by the same number. I can do this, no problem, but how do I create a new list featuring these new quotients?

I have tried:

```
for n in numbers:
    newnumbers = []
    newnumbers.append(n/649.00)
```

but it only gives me one number, the quotient of the last number in the list, back.

Comment: Look at where you are creating `newnumbers`. Think about what that means each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a loop you can also use a list comprehension (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
newnumbers = [n/649.00 for n in numbers]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's executing your code literally.

```
for each element in numbers:
   set newnumbers equal to an empty list
   add a value to newnumbers
```

So yes, of course you'll end up with a list with only one value in it.  What you want to do is move the list initialization out of the loop.

```
newnumbers = []
for n in numbers:    
    newnumbers.append(n/649.00)
```